# Jasmine Error: Expected undefined to equal

Tags: angularjs, html, jasmine

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error. I have a $scope.message in my angular application in my controller but when I put expect(scope.message)toEqual("It Works");  I get this Error can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong. It works when I render the application with index file, I'm using Jasmine and Karma for unit testing. Here is my code.

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController",['$scope', function($scope) {
console.log("Reaching Controller");

  $scope.message="Its Good";

   $scope.customer = {
   name: 'Naomi',
   address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };


}])


//normilized name factory function and should return an object
    app.directive('myCustomer', function(){
    return function(scope, elem){ //this for strictly testing 
     directives

    elem.append('<span>This span is appended from directive.</span>');
   };
});

 /*Here is my unit test
 describe("Hello PageCtrl working", function() {
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

   describe('Reaching Controller', function(){
       var scope,appCtrl, message;


      beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      appCtrl = $controller("MyController", {$scope:scope}); 

 })); 

        it("should have a message of Its Good", function () {
         expect(scope.message).toEqual("Its Good");
      });
   });
}); 


Thanks In Advance,
HP
```

Comment: post the full unit test

Comment: Also based on your example the message is "Its Good" not "It Works"

Comment: You are correct, mistake in my explanation. I  found out the issue, its with the name of the application.  It should be myApp. Thanks, HP